# How to execute some steps going through examples and do some more steps after the examples are done executing in cucumber feature file

Tags: cucumber

For Example:

```
@SanityTests
  Scenario Outline: Sanity Tests
    Do step1
    Do step2

    Examples:
      | Family |  | device      |
      | x      |  | a           |
      | y      |  | b           |
    Do step3
    Do step4
```

I tried as written above ended up having parser errors:
Exception in thread "main" cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: gherkin.ParserException$CompositeParserException: Parser errors: